# Website is not working on Google Cloud Hosting

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have worked on this website (https://www.udyamregistrationform.com/) for 2 year but now it is not working. I do not know why. Can anyone review and tell what is the issues.

Website is hosted on Google Cloud.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please, provide more information and, if possible, a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

Ping from [cloudshell](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/launching-cloud-shell#launching_from_the_console).

`ping www.udyamregistrationform.com` you will get

Name or service not known. Possibly a DNS issue.

Next ping the IP address of the VM to get confirmation. If that even fails then possibly a VM issue. If you are able to access your VM try to see if site is working locally.

```
curl localhost
```

Comment: I do not have technical knowledge, can you pls help me out with it. email me pls: helplineudyam@gmail.com